# How to query a Pervasive v13 database from a Docker Container?

Tags: pervasive, pervasive-sql

How can you query a [Pervasive v13 database](http://www.pervasive.com/database/Home/Products/PSQLv13.aspx) from an application that's running inside a [docker](https://www.docker.com/) container?

It would seem you'd have to install the pervasive sql client inside the docker container to accomplish this, but I cannot locate any documentation regarding this task.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would need to install the [Pervasive v13 client](http://www.pervasive.com/database/Home/Products/PSQLv13.aspx) within the Docker container.  You'd need to use the client for the OS of the container.  If the container is Linux based, use the Linux client.  If it's Windows, use the Windows client.